# Store text and audio in CSV file using Cordova(phonegap) in iOS device

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can I store text and audio information in a CSV file with Cordova(phonegap) in an iOS device ? I would also like to export it into the iOS device.

Comment: Grammar, writing, more clear

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend storing audio in a CSV, but if you have no choice, I would compress the audio as much as possible and then encode in Base64 (which basically turns it into a string) before putting it in the CSV.